# Create a ListView with Text and Favorite Icon based on SQLite Database Data

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-custom-view

I want to create a list where the listview will display a textview and an icon for each row. The diagram should be as follows:

[image]

Other than that, The data is retrieved from the database. The attribute of "favorite" will be checked first and if true, then the image in listview will be assigned with favorite_icon.png. Else, no icon need to be assigned.

I have been search for the related answer and tutorial, but all of them is too different from what I want and I cannot understand it very much. Hope somebody here can help me. Thank you in advance.

Comment: how will u identify that in the list this item is not favourite?
how are you storing data for favourite in DB?

Comment: @ChiragShah:  
There is column named as d_fav in database that will determine if the list is favorite or not. So before put the list into adapter or listview, it will be checked first. If it is favorite then use favorite icon. If not favorite, then do not use any icon or use icon other than favorite icon. Did my explanation is clear enough for you?

Comment: so put d_fav = 1 if favourite else d_fav = 0 in DB AND while generating listview take this all d_fav values in arraylist and check for the value.If its 1 then set fav_icon.png visible else not.

Comment: @ChiragShah : alright.. thanks for the hint. I am still working on it . thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I got after I have done my Homework

First we set up a custom layout for listview and also for the row of the listview we will use later.

Here is the custom_listview_main.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/customListView" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Here is the custom_listview_row.xml

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:minHeight="64dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/clv_imageView"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/empty"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="9dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/clv_textView"
    android:layout_width="97dp"
    android:layout_height="32dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:text="@string/tv_definition"
    android:textIsSelectable="true" />


    </RelativeLayout>
```

Then we need to customized how our Custom ArrayAdaptor will look and do.
But before that, make sure you have put your icon in the drawable folder.

Here is my MyPerformanceArrayAdapter.java

```
    import java.util.List;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class MyPerformanceArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<DefinitionObject>{
    private List<DefinitionObject> entries;
    private Activity activity;

    public MyPerformanceArrayAdapter(Activity a, int textViewResourceId, List<DefinitionObject> entries) {
    super(a, textViewResourceId, entries);
    this.entries = entries;
    this.activity = a;
    }

    public static class ViewHolder{
    public TextView item1;
    public ImageView item2;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater vi =
            (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = vi.inflate(R.layout.custom_listview_row, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.item1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.clv_textView);
        holder.item2 = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.clv_imageView);
        v.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
        holder=(ViewHolder)v.getTag();

    final DefinitionObject custom = entries.get(position);
    if (custom != null) {
        holder.item1.setText(custom.getWord());
        if(custom.getFav().equalsIgnoreCase("0"))
        {
            holder.item2.setImageResource(R.drawable.fav);
            holder.item2.setVisibility(holder.item2.INVISIBLE);
        }
        else
        {
            holder.item2.setImageResource(R.drawable.fav2);
        }
    }
    return v;
    }

    }
```

And lastly, here is my Activity to View the ListView using the CustomArrayAdaptor.

```
    import java.util.List;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.widget.ListView;

    public class TempCLV extends Activity {

private MySQLiteDefinitionHelper db;
String tblName = "";

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.custom_listview_main);

    Intent msjIntent = getIntent();
    tblName = msjIntent.getStringExtra(WordDefinitionHomeActivity.TABLENAME2);
    refresh();
    }

    public void refresh()
    {
    db = new MySQLiteDefinitionHelper(this);
    final List<DefinitionObject> values = db.getAllWords(tblName);

    ListView mylist = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.customListView);
    MyPerformanceArrayAdapter adapter = new MyPerformanceArrayAdapter(this, R.id.customListView, values);
    mylist.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
    }
```